# How to set global variables in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/process.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: '',
        success: function(output) {

var animal = output

        }
    });
```

I would like the `var animal` to be set globally so I can call it anywhere on the page even outside the ajax function's success callback. How to do this?

Comment: Keep in mind that your `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. I can sense a *"why is animal undefined?"* around the corner. ;o)

Comment: `console.log(typeof animal); `//possibly returns undefined due to uninitialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare it outside of any function or jQuery construct

```
var animal = null;

$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/process.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: '',
        success: function(output) {
            animal = output
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be a global variable, then declare it as a global variable. Generally you do this by putting

```
var animal;
```

around the top of your .js file. Then any reference to `animal` inside your code will be the global variable, unless you re-use the name somewhere else in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do it dynamically.

jQuery.globalEval()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/

This method behaves differently from using a normal JavaScript eval() in that it's executed within the global context (which is important for loading external scripts dynamically).

```
$.globalEval( 'var animal = ' + output );
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? Why would you down vote it?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `var` to make the variable global.

Note however that working with globals is generally viewed as bad practice, because they are very hard to debug.

Comment: IE doenst always define those variables so you can get some error's in IE